# Why is this off-topic/where should I ask?

Tags: support, closed-questions

I don't know for certain why this was closed as off-topic. I hate asking these types of questions, but having read the FAQ, I felt webmasters was the place to ask.

[Why do differant domains have differant prices?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/33302/why-do-differant-domains-have-differant-prices)

My guess is that since it's about the web in general, and not the direct operation of a website is why it was closed. But a lot of questions I see on here do not truly relate **directly** to `problems or issues that affect entire websites.`

Anyways, would love to know if this is the correct logic behind it, and if so, is there a place on SE I should ask / maybe even off.

Comment: When a question is closed, I really wish it gave more information why.

Comment: I'm guessing the upvotes / silence means it does seem odd?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The question arguably has little to do with managing a site, or in this case assets related to one. While there are plenty of questions accepted regarding finding where to register a particular odd TLD and so on, those are actual practical matters directly related to running a site. This particular question is really just economics.

[Because there's so much domain talk otherwise, I do agree John might've provided some context in this case, which may even have been something entirely other than what I said above.]

A seller can set their product at whatever price buyers will tolerate. `.tv` domains were launched at a relatively high price because the TLD controller figured TV show producers would pay a premium for eg. americanidol.tv (I've seen little evidence that plan worked out.) In contrast, most registrars seem to offer `.biz` at low prices because nobody ever really took that TLD seriously and it seems overrun with spam sites in my experience.

There are a few other instances like .tv where someone can point to specific reasoning for a given TLD's pricing, but ultimately there's no real answer to the question other than "That's what [whoever] decided the price would be."

Comment: Thanks for also answering my question. There's a few domain questions, but I guess I see the point. And while from your answer it is just economics, I could not have known that without an answer, as I wasn't sure if it had a technical reason or not. Thanks though :)